# Keep first parent in recursive (Start With... IN..., Connect By )

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion

I'm trying to keep track of the first parent given with an 'in' operator in a recursive query.

Here is the (highly simplified ;-) ) problem:

I have a table (myTable) with instrument interconnections like:

```
    SENSOR_IN | SENSOR_OUT
    ----------------------
            5 |         6
            3 |         5
            7 |         8
            2 |         7
            1 |         2
```

From this table I want to get a connection chain with "level" like:

```
    SELECT level, sensor_in, sensor_out
    FROM myTable
    START WITH sensor_out IN (6,8)
    CONNECT BY sensor_out = prior sensor_in
;
```

That will return me something like [didn't test, just to explain]:

```
    LEVEL | SENSOR_IN | SENSOR_OUT
    --------------------------------
         1          5 |         6
         1          7 |         8
         2          3 |         5
         2          2 |         7
```

I want know add a column called, let's say "first", giving for every line who is the primary parent (so the value given in the "IN()" statement, not the "true" primary parent in the table => wich is actually always the same in my particular case). Thus something like:

```
    LEVEL | SENSOR_IN | SENSOR_OUT | FIRST
    ---------------------------------------
         1          5 |         6  |      6
         1          7 |         8  |      8
         2          3 |         5  |      6
         2          2 |         7  |      8
```

Any (simple) idea?

Remark: if someone has a simple way to return the whole chain in one line for every "first", it's even better! Something like :

```
    FIRST | CHAIN
    -------------
        8 | 8;7;2
        6 | 6;5;3
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of functions that you should be able to play around with to get the results that you're after:

```
with mytable as (select 5 sensor_in, 6 sensor_out from dual union all
                 select 3 sensor_in, 5 sensor_out from dual union all
                 select 7 sensor_in, 8 sensor_out from dual union all
                 select 2 sensor_in, 7 sensor_out from dual union all
                 select 1 sensor_in, 2 sensor_out from dual)
SELECT level,
       sensor_in,
       sensor_out,
       connect_by_root sensor_out top,
       sys_connect_by_path (sensor_in, ';') path
FROM   myTable
START WITH sensor_out IN (6,8)
CONNECT BY sensor_out = prior sensor_in;

     LEVEL  SENSOR_IN SENSOR_OUT        TOP PATH      
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          5          6          6 ;5        
         2          3          5          6 ;5;3      
         1          7          8          8 ;7        
         2          2          7          8 ;7;2      
         3          1          2          8 ;7;2;1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `connect_by_root` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/operators004.htm#SQLRF51161) to get the root node:

```
SELECT level, sensor_in, sensor_out, connect_by_root sensor_out as first
```

Your example output doesn't match you data anyway, but just adding that to your query gives:

```
     LEVEL  SENSOR_IN SENSOR_OUT      FIRST
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          5          6          6 
         2          3          5          6 
         1          7          8          8 
         2          2          7          8 
         3          1          2          8
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dba96/1).

For the second part of your question, you can use that as a inline view and use `listagg()` to combine the values into one:

```
SELECT first, listagg(sensor_out, ';') within group (order by lvl) as chain
FROM (
  SELECT level as lvl, sensor_in, sensor_out, connect_by_root sensor_out as first
  FROM myTable
  START WITH sensor_out IN (6,8)
  CONNECT BY sensor_out = prior sensor_in
)
GROUP BY first
ORDER BY first
;

     FIRST CHAIN               
---------- --------------------
         6 6;5                  
         8 8;7;2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dba96/3).

Or using [more pseudocolumns](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/pseudocolumns001.htm):

```
SELECT first, chain
FROM (
  SELECT connect_by_root sensor_out as first,
    ltrim(sys_connect_by_path (sensor_out, ';'), ';') as chain,
    connect_by_isleaf as is_leaf
  FROM myTable
  START WITH sensor_out IN (6,8)
  CONNECT BY sensor_out = prior sensor_in
)
WHERE is_leaf = 1
;

     FIRST CHAIN               
---------- --------------------
         6 6;5                  
         8 8;7;2
```

[Yet another SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dba96/5).

Answer (score 1):

It can be a bit more verbose, but I find recursive SQL to be more intuitive, flexible, and standards-compliant (so, worth mastering because someday you may actually use a non-Oracle product) than connect-by.  Demonstrating ease with which various outputs can be calculated:

```
with mytable as (select 5 sensor_in, 6 sensor_out from dual union all
                 select 3 sensor_in, 5 sensor_out from dual union all
                 select 7 sensor_in, 8 sensor_out from dual union all
                 select 2 sensor_in, 7 sensor_out from dual union all
                 select 1 sensor_in, 2 sensor_out from dual union all
                 select 9 sensor_in, 10 sensor_out from dual union all
                 select 10 sensor_in, 9 sensor_out from dual 
                ),
recursive_cte (first_sensor, last_sensor, forward_chain, backward_chain, chain_length, next_sensor)
as (
    -- recursion base rows
    select  sensor_out                         first_sensor,
            sensor_in                          last_sensor,
            cast(sensor_out as varchar2(4000)) forward_chain,  
            cast(sensor_out as varchar2(4000)) backward_chain,  
            1                                  chain_length,
            sensor_in                          next_sensor
    from mytable  
    where sensor_out in (6,8,10)
    union all
    -- recursion inductive rows
    select  first_sensor                           first_sensor,
            next_sensor                            last_sensor,
            forward_chain || ';' || next_sensor    forward_chain,
            next_sensor  || ';' || backward_chain  backward_chain,
            chain_length + 1                       chain_length,
            sensor_in                              next_sensor
    from    recursive_cte 
            left join mytable on sensor_out = next_sensor
    where   next_sensor is not null
    )
    cycle next_sensor set is_infinite_loop to 'Y' default 'N'
select  first_sensor, last_sensor, forward_chain, backward_chain, chain_length, 
        is_infinite_loop 
from    recursive_cte
where   next_sensor is null
        or is_infinite_loop = 'Y'
order by first_sensor;

╔══════════════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╦════════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════════╗
║ FIRST_SENSOR ║ LAST_SENSOR ║ FORWARD_CHAIN ║ BACKWARD_CHAIN ║ CHAIN_LENGTH ║ IS_INFINITE_LOOP ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════╣
║            6 ║           3 ║ 6;5;3         ║ 3;5;6          ║            3 ║ N                ║
║            8 ║           1 ║ 8;7;2;1       ║ 1;2;7;8        ║            4 ║ N                ║
║           10 ║          10 ║ 10;9;10       ║ 10;9;10        ║            3 ║ Y                ║
╚══════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════╩════════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════════╝
```